# How do the Euler-Lagrange equations generalise to an arbitrary manifold?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, topology, action

So every formalism for the EL equations I have seen relies on choosing a coordinate chart.  However, if we had say, a field on a sphere, then we can’t have global coordinates.

How, in principle, would one get the eom of objects on a manifold that doesn’t have global coordinates?

Comment: You can use the variational bicomplex : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_bicomplex

Answer (score 0):

There are in principle no problems with the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) themselves since they are local in spacetime and target space, and can hence be expressed using local coordinates. Rather the problem could be that the action functional is not globally defined, but only defined within a local coordinate chart. For an example of the latter, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398159/2451) Phys.SE post.